# Wp_mail() function not working in Windows and MAC OS

Tags: wp-mail, linux, windows, mac

Not getting mails when sent from Windows OS and MAC OS but getting when sent from Linux OS.

I tried sending mails from LINUX OS,Windows and MAC OS LINUX sending me the mails as it should do but windows and MAC failing to send the mail I am getting `Mail sent successful` message, but not getting mails when sent from Windows or Mac OS.

Comment: you have setup your project locally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up in succeeding by using this [Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/) which converted  default Gravity forms Wp-Mail() to SMTP thus received mail from Windows and MAC OS too.

Answer (score 1):

My usual solution for this is a plugin called [WP Mail SMTP](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/). The problem with this is that the plugin has not been updated in over 2 years. This means that issues with more recent versions of WordPress (although at present that shouldn’t be the case) and also means you are likely on your own for support.

There are a few other plugins out there for this purpose as well.  Although not as popular (yet) as WP Mail SMTP, [Easy WP SMTP](http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/) looks promising. Another is [WP SMTP](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smtp/).  Using one of these plugins is an easy way to change your WordPress email configuration to send email via SMTP.

For more information on testing, troubleshooting, and changing your WordPress email configuration for wp_mail, here are some additional posts:

1. [Testing your WordPress email settings for the wp_mail function](http://www.butlerblog.com/2012/09/23/testing-the-wp_mail-function/) – some information on `wp_mail` and a testing script you can use to make sure it is sending messages.
2. [WordPress Email Settings: Changing the wp_mail address with a simple plugin](http://www.butlerblog.com/2011/07/14/changing-the-wp_mail-from-address-with-a-plugin) – here is a very simple and lightweight script you can load as a plugin to change the email address that WordPress sends email from.
3. [Changing the wp_mail from address in WordPress without a plugin](http://www.butlerblog.com/2011/07/08/changing-the-wp_mail-from-address-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin) – provides a simple code snippet you can use to change the email address that WordPress sends from, no plugin required.
4. [Easy SMTP email settings for WordPress](http://www.butlerblog.com/2013/12/12/easy-smtp-email-settings-for-wordpress) – how to change your WordPress email configuration to send email from a valid SMTP server with a simple script, no plugin required.

PS: If this stuff helps you please leave me a comment and support :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your inputs I installed Wp-mail-smtp plugin already and I am using Gravity forms this thing not working for me still :(

Comment: Ok, if you setting up WP Mail SMTP? This plugin should issue for windows server. It depends on your hosting server configuration and SMTP settings. To overcome from that you can use these plugins to send email from the wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to install the SMTP plugin and you should check for `wp_mail()` function.

Link : `https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/`

if you found the problem to setting please write me.